# PHP if(!empty) not working

Tags: php

I am using this `PHP` Code:

```
foreach ($_FILES['ticket_files']['name'] as $key => $value)
{
    if(!empty($_FILES['ticket_files']))
    {

    }
}
```

But if the file input is blank, it still thinks that there is a file there and runs the code.

Comment: Have you tried echoing the contents of the file, to see what it's seeing? It might be pulling up something you don't expect.

Comment: `empty()` does not check contents of files, it checks content of variables.  `$_FILES['ticket_files']` points to an array of information about the file uploaded - including `name` - so it will never be empty if a file was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach ($_FILES['ticket_files']['name'] as $key => $value)
{
    if(!$_FILES['ticket_files']['error'][$key])
    {
         //Do Stuff
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_FILES['ticket_files']['name'] as $key => $value)
{
    if (count($_FILES['ticket_files']) > 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Try this instead of what you have now.

Comment: this is still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (file_get_contents( $file_path )  == '')
{
    // file is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check the contents of the file to see if it's empty.

```
foreach ($_FILES['ticket_files']['name'] as $key => $value)
{
    if(!empty(file_get_contents($path . $_FILES['ticket_files']['name']))
    {
         //Do Stuff
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is uploaded $_FILES array looks like:

```
Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )
```

The error code 4 [error] => 4 indicates no file was uploaded and error code 0 indicates no error and file was uploaded. You can add below check instead of empty check.

```
if($_FILES['ticket_files']['error']==0) {
    // file uploaded, process code here
}
```